# Seasonal sens slope on times series water quality data for multiple categories in r - what format should the data be in?

Tags: r, trend

I have a water quality dataset with various parameters.  I would like to divide it into the wet and dry seasons to analyze the trend and its magnitude. I am very new at statistics especially R software. How do I format my data? Do I do create two data frames one for each season or use the season column to specify grouping during the analysis?

Here is the sample of the data:
`structure(list(Year = c(1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 1997, 1999, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005), pH =c(8.4, 8.2375, 8.27, 8.36666666666667, 8.4, 8.5, 8, 8.4, 8.28, 8.4, 7.8, 8.35), Colour = c(78, 21,19.3,39.3333333333333, 23, 20.6666666666667, 16, 23, 4, NA, 4, 27.5), Turbidity = c(44.9,2.60825,16.3095, 2.689, 11.2, 7.09333333333333, 74.3, 21.6, 7.1266, 0.552, 9.875, 7.985), Conductivity = c(53, 41.8125, 29.95, 35.5166666666667, 71.7, 62.1666666666667, 41.15, 41.7, 25.08, 41.1, 48.15, 45.95), TDS = c(355.1, 280.14375, 200.665, 237.961666666667, 480.39, 416.516666666667, 275.705, 279.39, 168.036,275.37, 322.605, 307.865), Na = c(38, 30.875, 18.1, 26, 72, 59.3333333333333, 23, 31, 13.8, 33,43, 39.5), K = c(3, 1.25, 2.1, 2, 3, 2.66666666666667, 5.5, 3, 2, 3, 2.5, 2.5), Ca = c(90, 88.125, 63, 60.4166666666667, 105, 100, 71.25, 77.5, 62, 67.5, 76.25, 81.25), Mg = c(75, 65.625,42.9166666666667, 57.6388888888889, 108.333333333333, 93.0555555555554, 54.1666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 38.3333333333333, 54.1666666666667, 68.75, 70.8333333333333), SO4 = c(58, 42.75, 30.8, 45.3333333333333, 91, 69.6666666666667, 53, 30, 15.6, 29, 45.5, 43.5), NO3 = c(NA, NA, 1.12222222222222, NA, NA, 0.55, NA, NA, 0.7, NA, 0.5, NA), SiO2 = c(9, 8.375, 14.6, 11, 1, 3.5, 7.5, 5, 14.2, 22, 12, 10.5), F = c(0.3, 0.325, 0.21, 0.3, 0.4, 0.333333333333333, 0.2, 0.5, 0.36, 0.3, 0.3, 0.35), Cl = c(42, 37.875, 17.5, 24, 66, 61, 23, 30, 11.2, 27, 41, 36), Alcalinity = c(117.8, 120.75, 89.6, 101, 168, 154.666666666667, 101, 148, 94.8, 132, 133, 141 ), Fe = c(0.03, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 0.0233333333333333,  NA, 0.05, 0.04, NA, 0.04, 0.025), Mn = c(78, 21, 19.3, 39.3333333333333, 23, 20.6666666666667, 16, 23, 4, NA, 4, 27.5), Cu = c(NA, 0.01, 0.0125, 0.032, 0.02, 0.0266666666666667, NA, NA, 0.026,  NA, 0.03, 0.015), Zn = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.02875, 0.025, 0.03,0.0233333333333333, NA, NA, 0.0225, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01), Season = c("Dry",  "Dry", "Dry", "Dry", "Dry", "Dry", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet", "Wet")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

I want to use the `Seasonal Mann Kendall`  for the trend and `Seasonal Sens slope` for the slope.

I tried `sea.sen.slope` but it gave an error that *a minimum of 2 seasons is required*.

Is the data in the right format? or should I do it separately for each season?

I did this for the seasonal trend:

````
DataSample %>% 
summarise(across(-1, ~ list(SeasonalMannKendall(as.ts(.))%>%
tidy %>% 
select(p.value, statistic)))) %>%
pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
unnest(c(value))```
````

Comment: Looking at the documentation of ```Kendall::SeasonalMannKendall´´´ the input needs to be: a vector or a time series comprised of consecutive monthly values. Your data only has two seasons for each year, so this method won't work. You can try grouping by Season and applying the normal Mann-Kendall trend test.

Comment: I get your point, Thank you. I will try that.. how do I apply the ```sens. slope``` to multiple categories?

Comment: `trend::sens.slope` also needs a time-series without missing time-steps, which your (at least sample) data is not. I am not sure what your ultimate goal is, but you might look at some other trend estimation method that does not need a regular time-series. Maybe someone else can suggest something.